# Upgrade Compatibility of Boost Serialization with binary archives armv7 to arm64

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization, arm64

The company I work for releases on iOS and Android, and now Apple is requiring we update all of our apps to run on the arm64 architecture (previously we only released for armv7). Unfortunately we have been using `boost::archive::binary_iarchive`'s (and `binary_oarchive`'s) to store a lot of user data (saved games, preferences, etc).

While testing, The loading of these archives that were saved by the armv7 binary, now fails spectacularly on arm64 devices running the "Universal Binary" version of our games.

```
template<typename T>
static T Deserialize(std::vector<char> buffer) {
    boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char> source(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char>> input_stream(source);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(input_stream); // crashes here
    T value;
    ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(value);
    return value;
}
```

The buffer we pass in is a reasonable size. Based on the fact that it is crashing during the constructor of `boost::archive::binary_iarchive` I am guessing it is failing to read the header properly.

This is the error that is logged:

```
(2005,0x19a1c0310) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=7598247065923108864) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
```

Is there any way we can upgrade, *and* keep users' saved data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep user's data you're gonna have to reverse engineer your way out of hell. You could maybe cheat by having the old data sent to a server for transformation.

For portable archives you can try the [OES Portable Archive](https://epa.codeplex.com/) implementation.

It is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for the standard binary archives and aims to be truly portable. Of course the results will not be binary compatible with the old format, so it's just a solution going forward.

Comment: Thanks. I was very much afraid of this. I think we might actually go the reverse engineering route for some of our data types anyway.